# Why does Wine crash when trying to install the VMware vSphere client?

Tags: wine, vmware

I'm trying to install VMware client on my Ubuntu with Wine but I'm getting errors during install:

> wine program crash internal errors invalid parameters received.

It seems is a Wine issue but I don't really know how to debug it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- [vSphere Client is known to be incompatible with Wine.](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=9860)
- [This VMware KnowledgeBase article](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1006095) advises using the web version of the client instead, which is somewhat limited, and discusses the differences.
- Unfortunately, the only practical way of running the Client on Ubuntu appears to be inside a Windows virtual machine.